# Create an olog for Wikipedia policy

Tags: category-theory

I really want to try my hand at formalizing some kind of conceptual argument as an olog, after David Spivak.

There are so many unknowns at the same time that I would really appreciate external guidance. I feel similarly to when I started learning Python, it took at least two years for me to be able to apply myself and teach myself what I needed to know with far more efficacy, speed and focus.

Let’s take the editorial policies of Wikipedia as an example. Spivak himself mentions one possible benefit or application of ologs, in his article, about handling things like law with far more rigor - you could use ologs to try to prove that a collection of laws are even self-consistent, say.

I will either use Coq or Lean4.

I guess the first thing to do I just start with any arbitrary object in the olog, say, “Wikipedia policy”, and start connecting it via morphisms to related concepts, and see how it grows?

Could anyone give a sample of a basic such olog?

Comment: Can you link to what an “olog” is and this article by David Spivak?

Comment: I would advise that you walk before you run. For example, prove that addition on natural numbers is commutative.